# How to create 4-level nested relationship with Prisma

Tags: graphql, prisma

I have 3 main types: Company, Service, and Specialty. Every Company has a list of Service. Every Service have a list of Specialty. Every Specialty have a list of Specialty (sub-specialties).

```
Company 1
- Service 1
-- Specialty 1
--- Sub-specialty 1
```

So
I am working on this datamodel on Prisma 1.34:

```
type Company {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String! @unique
  services: [Service]
}
type Service {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String! @unique
  companies: [Company]! @relation(link: TABLE)
  specialties: [Specialty]
}
type Specialty {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String! @unique
  companies: [Company]! @relation(link: TABLE)
  services: [Service] @relation(link: TABLE)
  sub_specialties: [Specialty] @relation(link: TABLE)
}
```

My problem is, when I add one Company and use the same Service for that Company in another Company, all other Specialty and Sub-specialty records are coming along with that Service. I want to make Specialty and Sub-specialty fields unique for every company but they also should be under related Service under every company.

I have been working on it for the past 3 days, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with: I am holding unique service and specialty names in `ServiceItem` and `SpecialtyItem` tables. Whenever I add a new `Service` to a company, I link that `Service` to a specific `ServiceItem` that is unique. That `Service` and `Specialty` receives it's information (only `name` property in this project) from linked `ServiceItem` and `SpecialtyItem`. That way, whenever I update my `ServiceItem` or `SpecialtyItem`, all related `Service` and `Specialty` fields under each company get updated. Here is the datamodel:

```
type Company {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String! @unique
  services: [Service]! @relation(onDelete: CASCADE)
}

type ServiceItem {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String! @unique
}

type Service {
  id: ID! @id
  info: ServiceItem! @relation(link: INLINE)
  company: Company! @relation(link: INLINE)
  specialties: [Specialty] @relation(onDelete: CASCADE)
}

type SpecialtyItem {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String! @unique
}

type Specialty {
  id: ID! @id
  info: SpecialtyItem! @relation(link: INLINE)
  service: Service @relation(link: INLINE)
  sub_specialties: [Specialty] @relation(onDelete: CASCADE)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're committed to a nested relationship, then you're going to have to make the `Service` type have non-unique names. This will force a new `Service` model to be created for each company while still allowing `Specialty` to be more generalized and have better reuse.

The logic here is that if there are multiple `Services` with the same name but with different `Specialty` attributes, then they are NOT the same.

Comment: I tried this method before posting here and it had other complications and weren't the best solution because later updating a name of Service in one company would only affect that company. I wanted Services to be also unique. So I came up with the solution I am posting as an answer right now: